# Clicking on the last element of multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have multiple `.home` elements and I want to click on the last one

Here is what i wrote:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.home');
const el = await page.$eval('.home', (elements) => elements[elements.length - 1]);
el.click();
```

But it does not work. Instead I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at open_tab (C:\wamp64\www\home_robot\robot.js:43:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:
```

Comment: Did you try getting all the `'.home'` elements and see what is actually there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`page.$$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleselector-1) to get all element handles of the `.home` elements and then you click on the last element in the array:

```js
const elements = await page.$$('.home');
await elements[elements.length - 1].click();
```

**Why your code is not working**

You cannot use [`page.$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) to return an element handle because the data you return there will be serialized via `JSON.stringify` when sending it from the browser to your Node.js environment.

Quote from the docs linked above:

> returns: Promise<[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)> Promise which resolves to the return value of `pageFunction`

As a DOM element cannot be serialized, you cannot click on it in your Node.js script and you get the error instead. You have to use `page.$` or `page.$$` to get the element handles.